# Oracle, invalid identifier error

Tags: oracle, select, oracle11g, subquery

I have this query that should:

> create a listing that identifies different items in the inventory
>   table on the number of colors available for each option

But I'm getting an error saying:

> Error at Command Line:167 Column:66 Error report: SQL Error:
>   ORA-00904: "INV"."ITEM_ID": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

```
SELECT inv.inv_id, 
item1.item_id, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT i.color FROM inventory i WHERE i.item_id = inv.item_id))
FROM inventory inv 
INNER JOIN item item1 
ON item1.item_id = inv.item_id
GROUP BY inv.inv_id, item1.item_id;
```

Comment: I've used [this tool](http://decapitalize.eu/) for fixing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want

```
SELECT inv.inv_id,
       item1.item_id,
       COUNT( distinct inv.color )
  FROM inventory inv
       JOIN item item1 ON (item1.item_id = inv.item_id)
 GROUP BY inv.inv_id, item1.item_id
```

There doesn't seem to be any reason to hit the `inventory` table again in a subquery.